# iOS Connection With XMPP Failed

Tags: ios, xmpp

I am developing a chat app in iOS using xmpp server. When i tried to connect to the server it returned 0 without any exception. All server credentials are true to the best of my knowledge. I tried many a times but couldn't found any fruitful help. Kindly give me a direction what should I do. Here is a code below.

```
xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];

//    [self setupStream];
    NSXMLElement *presence = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"presence"];
    [xmppStream sendElement:presence];

    [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"app.com"]];

    [xmppStream setHostName:@"appname.com"];
    [xmppStream  setHostPort:5222];

    NSError *error2;
    if ([xmppStream connect:&error2])
    {
        NSLog(@"Connected to XMPP.");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error connecting to XMPP: %@",[error2 localizedDescription]);
    }
    [self xmppStreamDidConnect:xmppStream];

//method is
- (void)setupStream {
    NSLog(@"setupStream in delegate");
    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    self.xmppStream.hostName = @"appname.com";
    self.xmppStream.hostPort = (port);
    [self connect];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the connection class given in [this link](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Xcode/iPhoneXMPP/Classes/iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate.m)

Connection to server returns “0” only when you specify wrong `HostName`,  `HostPort` or `JID`.

And one more thing you need not call  `xmppStreamDidConnect`  explicitly it will be called as delegate from `XMPPFramework`.